# Wanted to open notepad in Tomcat running as a service

Tags: java, tomcat

I have tried this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad");
```

It is working fine when I am running tomcat from console. When I tried with tomcat as service I am able to see in task manager but not in foreground .

I am trying the scenario only on server machine.

Comment: Why you want to see a service running in foreground? That's why both option given. Any service will run in background only.

Comment: just edit the question wanted to open notepad

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Problem in Runtime.getruntime which does not open notepad.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815727/what-is-problem-in-runtime-getruntime-which-does-not-open-notepad-exe)

Comment: i wanted to open on server machine only but still not able to open it

Answer (score 1):

A windows service is all about running in the background, unattended, when there's no user logged in to the machine. It's not enough to run as a specified user - you'd specifically need to connect to that user's desktop. Doing so would give your tomcat process tremendous permissions on the system - thus you shouldn't do this and design your application in a different way.

What you can do is: Run a server process on the user's desktop (e.g. it could be minimized to the windows tray) and connect to it from tomcat. When the application is there, tomcat will find it and can relay its requests to it (e.g. open Notepad). If it's not there, the user is obviously not logged in.

When you do this communication through TCP, there's nothing from a user account perspective that limits you - executing in another user's graphical context is prohibitively more complex. For good security-related reasons.